# React Native Flatlist rendered all items only for a millisecond

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, flatlist

I get my data from firebase, push the data into an array and render the items in flatlist component. What did i miss?

but list render the items only for a really short time.

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Box } from "native-base";
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import EventCard from "./EventCard.js";
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

// Silent warning about https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);

export default function Events() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [events, setEvents] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        let eventData = []
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(firestore, 'events'));
        querySnapshot.then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                eventData.push(doc.data())
                setEvents(eventData)
            })
        });
        setLoading(false);
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />;
    }

    return (
        <Box style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={events}
                keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (<EventCard key={Date.now()} eventData={item} />
                )}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
})
```

Thanks for your time. i really stuck.

Comment: Try moving `setEvents(eventData)` after `map()` instead of inside of map?

Comment: Oh lord. thanks. the next beer is on me, come over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `setEvents(eventData)` in the `map()` so after every iteration the state is being updated. Instead parse the data and then update state once.

```
querySnapshot.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    eventData.push(doc.data())
  })
  // After iterating over all docs
  setEvents(eventData)
});
```